# Literature on general paradox?

Tags: reference-request, logic, philosophy

I suppose this one teeters on the edge of un-mathematical, but here it goes...

I've been on something of a logic binge lately and have (surprise, surprise!) especially been interested in the results of Godel's Incompleteness Theorems. I understand that the vast, vast majority of mathematicians and logicians understand the result to imply the incompleteness of mathematics rather than its inconsistency, but I find it fun to play devil's advocate with these sorts of things. I'm interested in exploring the inconsistency side of the dichotomy.

Is there any good literature available (mathematical, logical, or just generally philosophical) which explores the nature of paradox itself rather than specific paradoxes? I know that there's some research in paraconsistent logic with true dialetheia. Is this worth exploring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Roy Sorensen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195179862) does.

Edit: +1 for the question. The book cited further provides Quine's *The Ways of paradox and other essays* ([Google docs](http://books.google.com/books?id=YReOv31gdVIC&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Answer (score 2):

Given the philosophy tag, here are a couple of philosophy books on paradoxes in general.

- [Tim Maudlin *Truth and paradox: solving the riddles*](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Truth_and_paradox.html?id=R7SkRePRR7wC)
- [Hartry Field *Saving truth from paradox*](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Saving_truth_from_paradox.html?id=8oRW3Gq_z6UC&redir_esc=y)
- [JC Beall *Spandrels of truth*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=W49VewAACAAJ&dq=beall%20spandrels&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SE8VT53-Lofx8QODg8iABA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA) (Beall seems to have a couple of other books on related topics)
- Also, lots of Graham Priest's work